# No Developer IDs are available for signing

Tags: xcode, macos, development-environment

I was hoping someone would be able to help with this issue I am having.

After archiving in Xcode and and choosing Export Developer ID-signed Application, I get this error:

> No Developer IDs are available for signing.

I have searched through other topics and none are about this error specifically.  I believe I have all of the correct certs installed in keychain.

Comment: What version of OS X and Xcode?

Comment: It is Xcode version 5.1.1 and OS X version 10.9.3.